# JavaScript "Class" Structure to avoid using x = new widget();

Tags: javascript

I would like use the following syntax where the parameter is an ID of HTML element, very similar as to how you setup JWPlayer but I can't figure out how they did it. This is so I can make it as simple as possible for someone else to use.

```
myWidget("htmlTargetId");
```

I'm trying to avoid having to do:

```
myWidget = new MyWidget("htmlTargetId");
```

I know that I can create the first by doing:

```
var myWidget = function(target) {
   // Do something here
}

myWidget("htmlTargetId");
```

I need to add methods and properties etc but I would like a "constructor" that will create elements in the "htmlTargetId". What would be the best way to do this?

I tried a few variations, this is the latest attempt:

```
var myWidget = (function () {

var _target = undefined;

// constructor
var widget = function (target) {
    _target = target;
    version = 12;
};

widget.prototype = {
    constructor: widget,
    doSomething: function () {
        console.log("I will so something to", target);
    }

};

return widget;
})();

// Try out the new code
myWidget("htmlTargetId");
console.log(myWidget.version);
myWidget.doSomething();
```

But this gives me "undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" I assume this is because the return statement is returning a function rather than an object because I'm not using "new"?

```
// Trying to avoid having to do this
superWidget = new myWidget("htmlTargetId");
```

Many thanks!

Comment: **Why** are you trying to avoid `new` ? `new` is the simplest way to create an instance in prototypal OOP.

Comment: If you modify `myWidget` in response to it being called (which you'd have to for `doSomething` to work), you can only use it as a singleton. As soon as you try to use it in two places, it won't work anymore. Sometimes, you see patterns used over and over and over again because they're *useful*. You'll want `var thisWidget = new myWidget("someid")` or `var thisWidget = myWidget("someid")` (where `myWidget` handles the creation of the new object) in order to make it useful more than once.

Comment: Also note that if you're returning something you've created within `myWidget` that needs to be used later, then *by definition* you need to store that result when calling it.

Comment: FWIW: `Object.create(prototype)` can be used to "avoid" `new` explicitly (ES5+), but it probably doesn't benefit anything in this case. You can always "hide" the new, eg. `function makeWidget() { return new .. }`, but for what end?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, just to clarify I didn't make it very clear. I don't mind using `new` in the script what I was trying to do was to make it as easy as possible for other people to use. So when they configure the widget the can use `myWidget("htmlTargetId", {config:options});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple `Widget` instances,

```js
var myWidget = (function () {

  // constructor
  var Widget = function (target) {
    this._target = target;
  };

  Widget.prototype = {
    constructor: Widget,
    version: 12,
    doSomething: function () {
      console.log("...", this._target);
    }
  };

  return function init(target) {
    return new Widget(target);

  };
})();

var widget1 = myWidget("foo"),
    widget2 = myWidget("bar");
console.log(widget1.version); // 12
widget1.doSomething();        // "..." "foo"
widget2.doSomething();        // "..." "bar"
```

However, if you only need one "instance", you don't need any constructor:

```js
var myWidget = function (target) {
  myWidget._target = target;
};
myWidget.version = 12;
myWidget.doSomething =  function () {
  console.log("...", myWidget._target);
}

myWidget("foo");
console.log(myWidget.version); // 12
myWidget.doSomething();        // "..." "foo"
```